# How can i setup the postgres dialect of jooq-codegen-maven plugin with liquibase and without db connection properties

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, jooq, dialect, jooq-codegen-maven

I use the liquibase and jooq and i need to generate my pojo's directly from liquibase xml files, but i have a problem to override the default "H2" dialect with Postgres. Actually, i've tried to setup dialect via property within plugin "configuration" section but it still uses H2. Can someone ask me please how can i make jooq use postgres dialect when reading xml files and generating java classes.

Here is the used libraries versions

```
<properties>
    <jooq.version>3.13.4</jooq.version>
    <vertx-jooq.version>5.1.1</vertx-jooq.version>
    <postgres.version>42.2.12</postgres.version>
 </properties>
```

Here is the my plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>jooq-generate</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgres.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.jklingsporn</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-jooq-generate</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx-jooq.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
      <artifactId>jooq-meta-extensions</artifactId>
      <version>${jooq.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <generator>
        <name>io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.generate.classic.ClassicReactiveVertxGenerator</name>
        <database>
          <name>org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase</name>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <key>scripts</key>
              <value>src/main/resources/liquibase/tenant/changelog.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property>
              <key>changeLogParameters.contexts</key>
              <value>!test</value>
            </property>
            <-- unfortunately this property doesn't work -->
            <property>
              <key>dialect</key>
              <value>POSTGRES</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
          <outputSchemaToDefault>true</outputSchemaToDefault>
          <unsignedTypes>false</unsignedTypes>
          <forcedTypes />
        </database>
        <generate>
          <daos>true</daos>
          <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
        </generate>
        <target>
          <packageName>org.folio.rest.jooq</packageName>
        </target>
        <strategy>
          <name>io.github.jklingsporn.vertx.jooq.generate.VertxGeneratorStrategy</name>
        </strategy>
      </generator>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.14, the [`org.jooq.meta.extensions.liquibase.LiquibaseDatabase`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-liquibase/) data source for the jOOQ code generator uses H2 behind the scenes to [simulate a migration](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/10/16/how-to-simulate-a-liquibase-migration-using-h2/), instead of actually running the migration on your target database. This allows for working with jOOQ and your liquibase migration scripts without an actual database instance and connection. In the future, it might be possible to spin up a PostgreSQL instance, transparently, using testcontainers: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6551

Here's an example how to set it up:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/main/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-testcontainers-example (not too hard)

If you wish to work with an actual PostgreSQL database, just run the liquibase migration using the liquibase maven plugins before you run the jOOQ code generation, having both connect to the same database server.

Comment: Hello @lucas-eder, Liquibase provides a possibilty to run in 'offline' mode. https://www.liquibase.org/blog/liquibase-without-a-database-connection

Maybe it will be possible to leverage this functionality?

Comment: @jumb0jet: How would that help, specifically?

Comment: @lucas-eder, sorry for disturbing. I had a wrong assumption on how jOOQ generates code based on schema definition and didn't notice it requires a real database running. I was thinking it will be possible to generate a DDL using Liquibase offline mode and then pass it to the `org.jooq.meta.extensions.ddl.DDLDatabase`.
But then I realized `DDLDatabase` uses H2 under the hood :|

Comment: @jumb0jet: It does, but that's an in-memory database that you don't have to start. `DDLDatabase` or `LiquibaseDatabase` start it for you, it should be transparent, unless you use vendor specific features. But you had something else in mind, I think? How would this offline mode help?

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to [Lukas Eder answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353193/13660214). You can try [pgljc-maven-plugin](https://github.com/raman-babich/dbljc-pgljc-maven-plugin) or [testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-jooq-codegen-maven-plugin) to reach your goal.

Example of pgljc-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.ramanbabich.dbljc</groupId>
  <artifactId>pgljc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${pgljc-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <postgresDockerImageName>postgres:15.3-alpine</postgresDockerImageName>
    <postgresJdbcDriverVersion>42.6.0</postgresJdbcDriverVersion>
    <liquibaseMavenPluginVersion>4.22.0</liquibaseMavenPluginVersion>
    <jooqCodegenMavenPluginVersion>3.18.4</jooqCodegenMavenPluginVersion>
    <liquibaseConfiguration>
      <!-- this section is the configuration section of the liquibase maven plugin to execute
      update goal, you can find more details on the official site.
      https://docs.liquibase.com/tools-integrations/maven/commands/maven-update.html -->
      <changeLogFile>/com/ramanbabich/dbljc/pgljcmavenplugin/liquibase/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml</changeLogFile>
    </liquibaseConfiguration>
    <jooqConfiguration>
      <!-- this section is the configuration section of the jooq codegen maven plugin to execute
      generate goal, you can find more details on the official site.
      https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-maven/ -->
      <generator>
        <database>
          <inputSchema>public</inputSchema>
        </database>
        <target>
          <packageName>com.ramanbabich.dbljc.pgljcmavenplugin.jooq</packageName>
        </target>
      </generator>
    </jooqConfiguration>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>pgljc-generate</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.